# Math operator for disconnection in adjacency matrix?

Tags: graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

So I'm implementing the model of a Telecommunication Network as a mathematical network object. Lets say my adjacency matrix is $M$ and its $M_{ij}$ element is 1. So, to simulate a disconnection, I just switch 1 to 0: $M_{ij}\leftarrow 0$.

Is there a standard operator for this? Say $M=f_d(M,i,j)$ disconnects branch $(i,j)$ in $M$.

What about considering a threshold? I mean, something like $f_d^{p_d}(i,j,p)$ disconnects branch $(i,j)$ if $p>p_d$.

What's the actual name of this? Dropout is very ML jargon.

Thank you!

Comment: How about $M-A^{(i,j)}$ where $A^{(i,j)}$ is 0 everwhere except for $A_{i,j}=M_{i,j}$. And the threshold can be integrated via an indicator function multiplied with $A^{(i,j)}$.

Comment: I do not see what you want to do with the equation $M=f(M,i,j)$.

Comment: Adjacency matrices are usually assumed to be symmetric. If you want to preserve this property, you will also have to change $M_{ji}$ to $0$. So the operator will probably be the linear map that sends $M$ to $M-E_{ij}-E_{ji}$ where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with a $1$ in position $ij$ and zeroes everywhere else. I am not aware of any name for this operation.